# Save the state of Collapse/Expand Groups in Grid Panel in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Iam working on a grid Panel.Iam using a grouping store in the grid panel.I wanted  to save the state of groups (expanded /Collapsed states) in grid panel. Is there a way to save the state when the page is refreshed?.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The GroupingView is already set up to be stateful, but you must have configured the [StateManager](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.state.Manager) with a valid provider in order for it to be in effect.  See the linked doc page for an example using the built-in CookieProvider.

Comment: There is no event that is thrown on a group being toggled, therefor the state of the group's expansion property is not saved on toggle.

Comment: This is completely false. The GridView is stateful, the GroupingView is not in anyway stateful.

Comment: Um, no. See the definition of GroupingView: `Ext.grid.GroupingView = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridView, {...`. So grouping view, in fact, inherits all of grid view's base state capabilities (sort state, scroll state), plus it has code internally to get/set group state (e.g., on group click: `this.grid.fireEvent('groupchange', this, this.grid.store.getGroupState());`). But yes, aside from that, it is totally not in any way stateful :P